# How to read data as a sequence of bytes separated by byte string

Tags: file, go

I have a file where there is a bunch of binary data separated by new lines in Go.

binarydata1 \n

binarydata2 \n

binarydata3 \n

How to read each chunk of binary data separated by newline in Go ? each chunk can have different undetermined size.

Comment: If you paste your question `How to read each chunk of binary data seperated by newline in GO ` into a search engine you will get the answer.